# Alining grid container center

Tags: html, css

```css
.wrapper {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80vh min-content 40vw repeat(3, min-content);
  grid-template-columns: 8rem 1fr repeat(8, minmax(min-content, 14rem)) 1fr;
}

.item-1{
  background-color: orangered;
}
.item-2{
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.item-3{
  background-color: pink;
}
.item-4{
  background-color: violet;
}
.item-5{
  background-color: blue;
}
.item-6{
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.item-7{
  background-color: red;
}
.item-8{
  background-color: darkred;
}
.item-9{
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item-1">sidebar</div>
      <div class="item-2">2</div>
      <div class="item-3">3</div>
      <div class="item-4">4</div>
      <div class="item-5">5</div>
      <div class="item-6">6</div>
      <div class="item-7">7</div>
      <div class="item-8">8</div>
      <div class="item-9">9</div>
    </div>
```

Hello, I saw this way of centering a container on a tutorial and I did the exact same thing but it doesn't work for me. I want the items 2-9 to be like a container( repeat(8, minmax(min-content, 14rem))) and 1fr on both sides should have equal margin, but item-2 doesn't behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your column 2 was starting in the wrong column (2) [1fr] so you have to tell it to start in grid-column 3.

```css
.wrapper {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80vh min-content 40vw repeat(3, min-content);
  grid-template-columns: 8rem 1fr repeat(8, minmax(min-content, 14rem)) 1fr;
}

.item-1{
  background-color: orangered;
}
.item-2{
  background-color: yellowgreen;
 grid-column:3;
}
.item-3{
  background-color: pink;
}
.item-4{
  background-color: violet;
}
.item-5{
  background-color: blue;
}
.item-6{
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.item-7{
  background-color: red;
}
.item-8{
  background-color: darkred;
}
.item-9{
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item-1">sidebar</div>
      <div class="item-2">2</div>
      <div class="item-3">3</div>
      <div class="item-4">4</div>
      <div class="item-5">5</div>
      <div class="item-6">6</div>
      <div class="item-7">7</div>
      <div class="item-8">8</div>
      <div class="item-9">9</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: doing this the 1fr or both sides doesn't show any effect, i want an space before 2 and after 9

Comment: There isn't enough space in the viewport to have anything between them (1fr)....if you want a gap, either reduce the width of 2-9 or set a specific gap instead of 1fr. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LYyrxrN

Comment: thanks, i added 2 extra empty divs to the html, maybe not the best solution but it works the way i wanted